# Bootstrap - Slider update range with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap slider](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) on a webpage where there are two sliders in one page. The range of the second slide is related to the value of the first slider.
The important thing is that I have to update the second slider range after it was created on the page load.

I found how to create and set the slider but not to update it. Look at example 2 in [this page](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/). Is there a way to change the slider range programatically with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: you means, min bar cant exceed max bar right ?

Comment: yes, if you have any idea for it

Answer (score 0):

according to the [bootstrap-slider docs](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#bootstrap-slider--) you can use the [$().slider().setAttribute() function](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#functions) to set the `max` value of a slider:

```
var slider = $("#foo").slider();
var slider2 = $("#bar").slider();
slider.setAttribute('max', slider2.getValue() + 10);  // or whatever
```